# How can you inject markup into a Vue component based off an error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to change the markup of my component when there is an error on my Vue application.

I know that you can use the `errorHandler` function to display the error in the console with the following code:

```
Vue.config.errorHandler = function(err, vm, info) {
  console.log(`Error: ${err.toString()}\nInfo: ${info}`);
}
```

I also see there is a method called `renderError` but from the Vue docs I see, it looks like all it can do is paste the code onto the page.

```
const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  renderError (h, err) {
    return h('pre', { style: { color: 'red' }}, err.stack)
  }
})
```

Is there a way to leverage this method to injecting or changing the markup on the page. What I'd like to do is inject an error template when an error occurs when using Vue.

Here's the article that details the examples above: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2019/05/01/handling-errors-in-vuejs

Comment: I don't think you need yo use any fancy Vue-specific functions to achieve what you want. What errors are we talking about? Possible AJAX failure? If so, put the request in a try-catch block, if an exception is thrown, use the Error.message in your component's state(a special field like , "errorString"), which will be shown in your markup.

Comment: Yeah it's for an Ajax failure. I was probably overthinking it with using Vue for that sort of error handling.

I ended up setting a variable that would return a boolean based on if the Ajax response is a 200 or not and then dynamically show the error in the template with v-if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to return a Boolean. Using booleans for error-handling is generally bad practice. You need to rely on try-catch blocks and exceptions. For instance, assuming you're using axios for http requests:

```
fetchItems: async function() {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://someurl.com/items/');
    const items = data;
    this.items = items;
  } catch (error) {//Any status code above  the 200 range will throw an exception in axios.
    this.errorMessage = error.message;//use this.errorMessage in the template, declaratively.
  } finally {
    //Here you can do something, regardless if the request succeeded or not.
  }
}
```

This is much cleaner, simpler and error-proof.

Comment: This works, we're using Axios so I was able to use your implementation. Thanks!

Comment: Notice something interesting: When would you use the "finally" clause? If you have some "loader" that you want to turn on and off, during the request, u can turn it on in the try clause, and then turn it off in the finally clause, because it needs to stop in both success and an error.

Answer (score 1):

I was probably overthinking it with using Vue for that sort of error handling. I ended up setting a data attribute in my Vue Component that would return a boolean based on if the Ajax response is a 200 or not and then dynamically show the error in the template with v-if.